# Codeception Exception: json_encode(): type is unsupported

Tags: php, laravel, json, codeception

When trying to run any test I get the following error:

json_encode(): type is unsupported, encoded as null

I'm using v 2.0.1

Test code:

```
$I = new ApiTester($scenario);
$I->wantTo('get a list of all users');
$I->haveHttpHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
$I->sendGET('users'); // <-- error happens here
$I->seeResponseCodeIs(200);
$I->seeResponseIsJson();
$I->seeResponseContains('{ result: ok}');
```

Example output below:

```
Trying to get a list of all users (GetUsersCept) Scenario

    I have http header "Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

    I send get "users"
    [Request] GET http://api.myapp.com/users
    ERROR

    [ErrorException]
    json_encode(): type is unsupported, encoded as null

    Exception trace: () at /app-dir/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/Log/JSON.php:280 
    Codeception\Subscriber\ErrorHandler->errorHandler() at n/a:n/a json_encode() at /app-dir/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/Log/JSON.php:280 
    PHPUnit_Util_Log_JSON->write() at /app-dir/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/Log/JSON.php:266 
    PHPUnit_Util_Log_JSON->writeCase() at /app-dir/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/Log/JSON.php:94 
    PHPUnit_Util_Log_JSON->addError() at /app-dir/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestResult.php:275 
    PHPUnit_Framework_TestResult->addError() at /app-dir/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestResult.php:760 
    PHPUnit_Framework_TestResult->run() at /app-dir/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestCase.php:753 
    PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase->run() at /app-dir/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestSuite.php:675 
    PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite->run() at /app-dir/vendor/codeception/codeception/src/Codeception/PHPUnit/Runner.php:100 
    Codeception\PHPUnit\Runner->doEnhancedRun() at /app-dir/vendor/codeception/codeception/src/Codeception/SuiteManager.php:153
    Codeception\SuiteManager->run() at /app-dir/vendor/codeception/codeception/src/Codeception/Codecept.php:167
    Codeception\Codecept->runSuite() at /app-dir/vendor/codeception/codeception/src/Codeception/Codecept.php:150
    Codeception\Codecept->run() at /app-dir/vendor/codeception/codeception/src/Codeception/Command/Run.php:198
    Codeception\Command\Run->runSuites() at /app-dir/vendor/codeception/codeception/src/Codeception/Command/Run.php:149
    Codeception\Command\Run->execute() at /app-dir/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Command/Command.php:252
    Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() at /app-dir/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:887
    Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() at /app-dir/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:193
    Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() at /app-dir/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:124
    Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at /app-dir/vendor/codeception/codeception/codecept:27
```

I'm also getting the error for a simple acceptance test for the Laravel default welcome page:

```
$I = new AcceptanceTester($scenario);
$I->wantTo('see the Laravel welcome page');
$I->amOnPage('/');
$I->shouldSee('You have arrived.');


Acceptance Tests (1) ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Modules: PhpBrowser, AcceptanceHelper
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Trying to see the Laravel welcome page (HomeTestCept)
Scenario:
* I am on page "/"
 ERROR




  [ErrorException]
  json_encode(): type is unsupported, encoded as null
```

Comment: Show us your test case code

Comment: thanks @Unnawut, test code added.

Comment: Are you certain you need `$I->haveHttpHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');`? Maybe try remove that line. IMO, doing a simple `GET` should not need that and it might have effects on how your code is encoding/decoding JSON data.

Comment: Tried removing all but the sendGET call and getting the same error. From other posts it often seems to be due to an invalid URL, however my URLs are working from browser or cURL requests. 

Would be nice if there was a more descriptive error message..!

Comment: Speaking of more descriptive error message try adding `--debug --verbose` when you run the command e.g. `codecept --debug --verbose` :p

Comment: Or perhaps your controller is not returning a properly formatted JSON response?

Comment: Added more info - its also failing from a simple acceptance test for the Laravel default landing page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be an issue with timezone not being set in php.ini. I added the relevant line to /etc/php.ini and it now works.

Example /etc/php.ini: (PHP 5.4.19)

```
date.timezone = "Europe/London"
error_reporting  =  E_ALL
display_errors = On
html_errors = On

zend_extension=/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/xdebug.so

extension=mcrypt.so
```

See https://github.com/Codeception/Codeception/issues/1165 for details.